# Как сделать это более грамотно в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть в базе данных 2 таблицы, `новости` и `история`. История само собой выводится на главной странице. 
 Так вот у меня есть форма, я отправляю post запрос, и у меня должно добавлять одновременно в две базы данных, в историю и новости. 
Как это реализовать более грамотно? Чтобы к примеру **не писать** вот так в одном контроллере:

```
public function addNews()
{
    $history = new History;
            $history->admin_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $history->title = $request->title;
            $history->action = "Добавил новость";
            $history->url_address = "news/create";

    $addNews = new News;

       $addNews->author_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $addNews->title = $request->title;
            $addNews->description = $request->description;

...
```

То по моему мнению так не грамотно писать будет, так как не соответствует solid принципам.

Comment: Как по мне все норм, куда тут еще упрощать. Смотришь на код и все быстро понятно, это самое главное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Сразу предлагаю Вам вынести валидацию в отдельный класс, поскольку здесь Вы получаете все данные из $request, который сейчас даже нигде не описан. Примерно так:

```
public function addNews(StoreNewsRequest $request)
{
...
}
```

2.Историю лучше вести с привязкой через полиморфические связи. Таким образом, в БД всегда будет храниться история взаимодействий с данной новостью, а Вы сможете легко посмотреть, кто и что делал с этой новостью на протяжении всего времени. Больше про полиморфические связи в Eloquent [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

3.Писать в коде прямым текстом вот так: `$history->action = "Добавил новость";` - зло. Лучше это вынести в константу модели `History`:

```
class History 
{
   const USER_ADDED_NEWS = "Добавил новость";
}    
...
$history->action = History::USER_ADDED_NEWS;
```

В заключении посоветую почитать [эти best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC), явно много нового и полезного для себя найдете :)